# Gradient colors from data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, gradient

I'm trying to get gradient colors from data-attribute with granim.js plugin; https://sarcadass.github.io/granim.js/examples.html

```
<canvas id="canvas-basic" class="granim" data-granim-opacity="[1, 1]" data-granim-colors="[ ['#AA076B', '#61045F'],['#02AAB0', '#00CDAC'],['#DA22FF', '#9733EE'] ]"></canvas>
```

Here is the variations;

```
$('.granim').each(function(){
        var item = $(this),
        granimOpacity = $(item).data('granim-opacity'),
        granimColors = $(item).data('granim-colors');
        var granimInstance = new Granim({
            element: '.granim',
            name: 'basic-gradient',
            direction: 'left-right',
            opacity: granimOpacity,
            isPausedWhenNotInView: true,
            states : {
                "default-state": {
                    gradients: granimColors
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Opacity is works good but gradients colors didn't work.

Demo; https://codepen.io/anon/pen/owqbaK

Comment: can you provide demo  then i can help you

Comment: Hey... I just guess here. but `opacity` is an array of integer. Fine. But where you use `granimColors`... It just ain't an array or an object *as a string*... Something to wrap is missing around your "granimColors" string.

Comment: here is a demo; https://codepen.io/anon/pen/owqbaK i created it from this https://codepen.io/JonathanSchndr/pen/KgVmLo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `granimColors` as an array.

The `gradients` attribute [is expecting](https://sarcadass.github.io/granim.js/examples.html) an array of arrays.

```
$('.granim').each(function(){
  var item = $(this),
    granimOpacity = $(item).data('granim-opacity'),
    granimColors = $(item).data('granim-colors');

  var granimInstance = new Granim({
    element: '.granim',
    name: 'basic-gradient',
    direction: 'left-right',
    opacity: granimOpacity,
    isPausedWhenNotInView: true,
    states : {
      "default-state": {
        gradients: [granimColors] // Change this
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: So what is expected is an array of array. Can you provide a link to documentation proving this *(would be usefull to future readers)*?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it but couldn't get a solution. updated it on question.